# curl with nghttp2 on ubuntu on raspberry pi3

Tags: swift, ubuntu, curl, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install nghttp2 on pi3 running ubuntu.
when i typed:

```
curl --version
```

result:

```
curl 7.52.1 (armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf) libcurl/7.47.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2g zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

the version showed above that doesn't support http2.

I need to type this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib /usr/local/bin/curl --version
```

result:

```
curl 7.52.1 (armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf) libcurl/7.52.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2g zlib/1.2.8 nghttp2/1.23.0-DEV librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy
```

This curl supports http2. I know I can install as many curl versions in the same system as I want.

My question is, how can I make the curl officially in the system supports http2?

As I am using swift language that one of the modules will link to "include/curl.h" header file which requests to support http2.
on x86 ubuntu this problem won't happen. when I type the command to print the version, it prints out the curl that supports http2.

Comment: According to this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/884899/how-do-i-install-curl-with-http2-support, the recommended option is to install from source.

Comment: @DaveWeston Sorry, this is not the answer I want. The answer above prevents collide the other version of curl. But this is what I need. I need this version of curl as the one my program would link to. Now, my program won't link to the Library of the curl version I want. So, I said I want to make me officially support in my system.

Comment: You can also remove the system one. Are you using SwiftPM to link in curl? Can you update your question with the contents of your Package.swift?

Comment: @DaveWeston I did remove the system one. And I still need to type this command. If I remove, when I build, it showed error as swift compiler can't find the header file.

Comment: What are you trying to build that depends on libcurl?

Comment: @DaveWeston "vapor-apns" for Apple push notification. Need it to preform safe-connection the apple server.